# GGTS 3.6.4 (OSX 64 bit) error - System property http.nonProxyHosts has been set to local

Tags: macos, grails, ggts

I am running Groovy/Grails Tool Suite 3.6.4 IDE on a macbook pro running Yosemite (10.10.3), with Java8. At launch I get an error "System property http.nonProxyHosts has been set to local|*.local|169.254/16|*.169.254/16 by an external source. This value will be overwritten using the values from the preferences"

Session data for the error:

```
eclipse.buildId=3.6.4.201503100339-RELEASE-e44
java.version=1.8.0_40
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86_64, WS=cocoa, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.springsource.ggts.ide -keyring /Users/slacher/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation
Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86_64 -product org.springsource.ggts.ide -keyring /Users/slacher/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation
```

It doesn't seem to impact development, but I'm unsure how to address the error.  What external source would be setting this? What is the http.nonProxyHosts system property?

Comment: What are your network settings?  DO you have proxy exceptions set up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aha, I think that's the issue.  I didn't set them myself, but in my network preferences, I had an entry for "*.local, 169.254/16" listed under "Bypass proxy settings for these Hosts & Domains:"  (Network settings, wi-fi, advanced... button, proxies tab).

I emptied out the field, and everything seems okay now.  See this tech note for more info.

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3111696